# How can I use Glyphicons in a button with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do the typical +/- button with `Bootstrap` but I want to use the `Glyphicons` instead of a + or - character.

I know that the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use) says:

> **Don't mix with other components**
>
> Icon classes cannot be directly combined with other components. They should not be used along with other classes on the same element. Instead, add a nested `<span>` and apply the icon classes to the `<span>`.

but I think it should be a way to put a `Glyphicons` on a button and I cannot get it out.

If not, is there something to achieve the same behaviour?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dbTqC/1007/) is my code snippet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What’s wrong with simply inserting a span element into your button, as the documentation tells you to …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `span`-container somewhere within your [`button`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)-container.

Something like this...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> 
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is just exactly what I needed :). I though that `Button groups` should be the best option but now I can see that I was wrong. Again, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> </button>
```

Hope this helps :)